# Is there a nice way to set directory/project local environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables

I have been working on several projects, and they require different environment variables (e.g., `PATH` for different versions of `clang` executables, `PYTHONPATH` for several external modules). Whenever I work on one project, I have to modify these environment variables myself (e.g., change `.zshrc`/`.bashrc` and `source` it); and I sometimes forget and make mistakes.

Is there a way/project that helps do this automatically, similar to what [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) does in Python?

Comment: The [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) package may do what you want.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Is there a similar one that is documented and maintained well?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There're mature tools designed to set environment variables for a specific directory.

Compared with other tools designed for this, [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) is the best of them. One of the main benefit is that it supports **unload**ing the environment variables when you exit from that directory.

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the current directory. This allows **project-specific environment** variables without cluttering the `~/.profile` file.

What makes `direnv` distinct between other similar tools:

- `direnv` is written in Go, **faster** compared with its counterpart written in Python
- `direnv` supports **unload**ing environment variables when you quit from the specific dir
- `direnv` covers many shells

Similar projects

- [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) - one of the oldest (in a good way) environment-loading systems
- [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) - lightweight; doesn't support unloads; slow written in Python
- [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) - a feature-rich mixture of autoenv and [smartcd](https://github.com/cxreg/smartcd): enter/leave events, nesting, stashing (Zsh-only).
- ~~[asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)~~, asdf is a plugin manager to switch different versions of the same executable. NOT a env switcher at all.

Answer (score 4):

For zsh, this is very easy to do by invoking `add-zsh-hook` on the `chpwd` event.

```
env_on_chdir () {
    case $PWD in
        /home/user/path/to/dir )
            export GO111MODULE=on;
            ;;
        /home/user/other/dir )
            export NO_COLOR=true;
            ;;
        * )
            # change background, when entering any other directory
            export GO111MODULE=off;
            unset NO_COLOR;
            ;;
    esac
}

# add env_on_chdir to chpwd_functions
add-zsh-hook chpwd env_on_chdir
```

For more, see https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/42-ZSH-Gem-8-Hook-function-chpwd.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yuch, too much maintenance and too much individual stuff.
I'd recommend putting most of the effort into having appropriately scoped names that are appropriate for the platform so you can just have all of them all of the time.  PYTHONPATH is a good example... you're unlikely to want to repurpose it for a Ruby project...  You can group and mark the group with comments in the `.bashrc` to ease maintenance.
It is not always possible to do that, i.e.. when there is conflict (plus it requires editing and not using discrete files) and sometimes you will need a framework specific setup file.  One approach to that is to have aliases setup to run them, e.g.

e.g.

```
alias pp='. ~/pp.setup' # For using Python
alias rb='. /rb.setup'  # For using Ruby
```

You could also create a function, something like 'switcher' that uses/sets a variable and just switches using a parameter passed in, or just toggles to what isn't current.

Comment: This is a great point.  If possible, install your different versions of clang so you can run them as `cc-clang3.2` or whatever, so you can use any version at any time just by running it.

Answer (score 1):

There are management tools such as **[modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)**, that allow dynamic modification of a user's environment... though this one is no longer developed; last version is from 2012

Example:

```
$ module load gcc/3.1.1
$ which gcc
/usr/local/gcc/3.1.1/linux/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Update on this - modules project is alive as of Jan 2020.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[direnv](https://direnv.net/)** to load environment variables on directory change. From its homepage:

> direnv is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or unload environment variables depending on the current directory. This allows project-specific environment variables without cluttering the ~/.profile file.

I am using it with the `xonsh` shell (via a small additional plugin) and it works excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can source any file you like, it doesn't have to be `.zshrc`.  You could make an env-setup script for each different project, and keep it in the project directory.

If you want to be able to start new shells and have them load the env settings, you have a couple options:

- Always start your shells in the project directory, and have your `.zshrc` `[[ -e ./PROJECT-ENV.sh ]] && source ./PROJECT-ENV.sh` (which you keep there).  **DANGEROUS**: starting a new shell in a directory with hostile contents runs whatever code is in the file you source.
- `.zshrc`: `source ~/current-project.sh`.  update current project with `ln -sf "$PWD/THIS-PROJECT-ENV.sh ~/current-project.sh`

If only a few commands for each project need the env vars set, you could make wrapper scripts for them that set the variables, and then leave your shell rc file untouched.

Another idea: you could hack something into PROMPT_COMMAND, which runs before every prompt is displayed.  Or hook cd/pushd/popd by writing shell functions with those names which check/set env vars and then run `builtin cd`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that wrapper is enough when only a few of commands  are needed. child-shell with PROJECT-ENV.sh seems the most efficient way  for me and the only trick is that I should remember to exit it.

Comment: or just source a different `PROJECT-ENV.sh` after you cd, but then you have the problem of remembering to change vars.  Maybe have `PROJECT-ENV.sh` also modify your `PS1`, or make the build scripts for each project look for something so they can detect that you have the wrong setting when you do something common.  Then you can fix your shell so everything works.

Comment: I editted in another idea: you could hook `cd` to check / set your vars.

Comment: I think I'll choose to change `PS1`. Using `PROMPT_COMMAND` is too noisy; and changing `cd` is not optimal since sometimes I need to use the project settings but inside other external directories(e.g., for testing purposes).

Comment: I meant putting a function call in `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a function that checks your current directory, and updates env vars.  But if you don't ALWAYS want your env vars to silently change (or non-silently), then that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Peter Cordes and @Michael Durrant's answers, I came up with a limited and lightweight solution for *my special case*.

Firstly let me re-illustrate my real issues.

> I need to use different llvm related executables (`clang`, `llvm-config`, etc) that are under project local directories, and I need to use 1 default version for general purpose (compiling, etc). I also need to need to use different python modules (llvm python bindings) inside different local directories.

Since all my llvm related projects are built with similar directory structures, I specify the llvm version related environment variable (`MY_LLVM_VERSION`) and add the directories to `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`. I used a function named `_my_llvm_version` that customize the variable *interactively*. As functions only have effects inside it, I use aliases to do the real *source* work.  Then let `MY_LLVM_VERSION` defaults to my commonly used one (*git*). These are all inside `~/.zlocal` that will be sourced for an interactive zsh. (Full file is [here](https://github.com/HongxuChen/dotfiles/blob/master/Linux/_zlocal)). By sourcing `~/.zlocal`, I'm able to change `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` according to `MY_LLVM_VERSION`.

```
function _my_llvm_version() {
    available=("3.3" "3.4" "3.5" "git")
    USAGE="my_llvm_version 3.3|3.4|3.5|git"
    if [ $# -ne 1 ] || ! (( ${available[(I)${1}]} )); then
      echo "usage: $USAGE"
    fi
    MY_LLVM_VERSION="$1"
}
alias my_ll33='_my_llvm_version 3.3;source ~/.zlocal'
alias my_ll34='_my_llvm_version 3.4;source ~/.zlocal'
alias my_ll35='_my_llvm_version 3.5;source ~/.zlocal'
alias my_llgit='_my_llvm_version git;source ~/.zlocal'
: ${MY_LLVM_VERSION:=git}
```

I think it should be **more maintainable** and do not invoke a child shell. It should be useful to add llvm version to `PS1` area, but currently I do not need that.

Of course, this solution is *not* general and *not* a real solution to my original question.